# Copying a CiviCRM/Drupal install from one server to another (got error)

Tags: civicrm

I've tried copying a a CiviCRM/Drupal install from 1 server to another. I copied all the files within the drupal root, and the database, and changed the database details in both Drupal's settings.php file and CiviCRM's civicrm.settings.php file. Drupal now works fine - copying this over appears to have worked, and I've done so succesfully with the same method many times. However, CiviCRM is not fully working. When I visit the main CiviCRM admin page (ie. http://cea-crm.philosofiles.com/civicrm/ on my server) I see CiviCRM's sidebar boxes (indicating it's working to some extent) but, to the right of them, see:

> Page not found
>
> The requested page "/civicrm/" could not be found.

When I click on any sidebar box link, such as 'My Contact Dashboard', I likewise see:

> Page not found
>
> The requested page "/civicrm/user?reset=1" could not be found.

Presumably I've missed some change I needed to make to reflect my new server setup? I can't *see* anything in civicrm.settings.php I still need to change, e.g. I've added lines like `define( 'CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL'      , 'http://cea-crm.philosofiles.com/' );` and `$civicrm_root = '/home/myusername/public_html/d7/sites/cea-crm.philosofiles.com/modules/civicrm';`

Answer (score 5):

If you have Drush installed, you can also use the following command to update some of those settings:

`drush civicrm-update-cfg`

It will try to update the URL and directory settings, which is pretty equivalent to the URL: "http:///index.php?q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1".

After that, you can use the API to flush various CiviCRM caches which may be using that data:

`drush civicrm-api system.flush`

Answer (score 1):

Moving CiviCRM from one server to another can be a real pain. You need to make sure that you don't copy the data in the CiviCRM cache tables of the database and then review CiviCRM settings after the move using messy URLs. CiviCRM unfortunately saves a lot of server config data in the database that you need to clear out to successful make the transition.

This forum post has helped me a lot in the past:-

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=15052.0

Comment: I'm seeing similar symptoms to the OP.  Unfortunately the same also affects the links in steps 8 through 10 of the page at the URL drmonkeyninja posted.  Page not found.

Comment: @drmonkeyninja you may be interested in supporting the new [CiviCRM SE site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm?referrer=8gfMpihOSETXeNHrjdyxXQ2), we'd love to have you!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If referenced page will ever disappear, your answer will become useless.

Answer (score -1):

This page on the CivicRM wiki: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location
is very helpful on moving an installation to a different server.

Also you can override lots of the settings by putting override staements into civicrm.settings.php as described on this wiki page: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Override+CiviCRM+Settings

Comment: Whilst these links may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: As the answer doesn't really have any "essential parts" in my view - i.e. the answer is to follow a carefully set out workflow as described in detail on the referenced wiki page, I did not and do not feel it that is is helpful to provide a partial answer to the person asking the question. much better simply to provide the link to where the guidance is set out in full. I agree that link-only answers rely on the linked page remaining relevant. In this case the linked page will be more relevant than a partial answer here which is far more likely to become out of date.